# No alert when child turns 6 - not in disabled alerts

Tags: crusader-kings-2

For some reason I am no longer getting alerts when a child turns 6 so I can educate them.

It's not listed in the Disabled Alerts list in the outlier, and I can't find it in the message settings.

How do I re-activate the alert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it turns out this is part of the Conclave expansion. Children are automatically assigned their parent as a "guardian", unless you specify an "educator". [Wiki page on education in Conclave](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Education_(Conclave))